# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "=": syntax error with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

This is my code:

```
 cursor.execute("UPDATE students SET (firstName = %s, lastName = %s, birthDate = %s, studentMark = %s) WHERE id = %s" % (firstName, lastName, birthDate, studentMark, findStudent))
```

And this is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\Coursework\main.py", line 102, in <module>
    cursor.execute("UPDATE students SET (firstName = %s, lastName = %s, birthDate = %s, studentMark = %s) WHERE id = %s" % (firstName, lastName, birthDate, studentMark, findStudent))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "=": syntax error
```

Can you please help me fix this :D Thank you

Comment: Sqlite uses `?` for parameters, not `%s`. I think that's a MySQL thing? Plus that `%` outside the string should be a comma.

Comment: I have tried both and still i get the same message

Comment: The parentheses around all the columns you're updating might be an issue too.

Comment: Yep its was the parentheses... lol Thanks a lot